# Highcharts is not defined webpack

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack

Im trying to install Highcharts with npm on my project and im gettin this error

> Uncaught referenceError: Highcharts is not defined.

I followed the docs and i can not draw a chart.

This is in my app.js

```
var Highcharts = require('highcharts'); // Load module after Highcharts is loaded require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);
```

and this is in my blade.php

```
<script>
  Highcharts.chart('container', { /Highcharts options/ });
</script>
```

PD: i have use npm run dev but it still not working.

Comment: seems typo mistake `Uncaught referenceError: Highcarts is not defined.`

Comment: @Dreamy Player Oh sorry my bad i just wrote it not pasted it. im making que correction

Comment: seems two files did you require that package in `blade.php` file or imported?

Comment: i want to use Highcharts globally just like sweet alert